# A question of open mapping

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$\text { Let } X \text { and } Y \text { be Banach spaces. Suppose that } A \in \mathcal{B}(X, Y)$ and $A$ is an open mapping, is range$(A)=A(X)$ also an open subspace of $Y$? I know that a open map maps open set to open set, how about the range?

Comment: What is $x{}{}$?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: $X$ is open in $X$ so $A(X)$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks

Comment: Check the definition of "open mapping" that is in use. Annoyingly there are authors who call a map open if it is open as a map to the range. Then the range of an open mapping can be arbitrary.

Comment: @DanielFischer Annoyingly, there are  too many authors who call the morphisms of a category always *homomorphism*. In an additive category with kernels and cokernels  a morphism is called a homomorphism if the induced morphism between the cokernel and the image is an isomorphism. Then the operators which are open onto their range are precisely the homomorphisms in the category of Banach spaces.

Comment: @Jochen Provided that the range is closed. // But wasn't the term "homomorphism" in use before categories were invented?

Comment: If an operator between Banach spaces is open onto is range, the range is necessarily closed because quotients of Banach spaces are Banach, no? // You are right, the origin is discussed here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280261/whence-homomorphism-and-homomorphic

Comment: @Jochen Yep, right. Rookie oversight there.